# Matlab code with % symbol?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm supposed to replicate a model, but I have never came across a matlab code that has some code in the % area before. When I did simple assignments, it was just matlab code and anything with % means that it is just preformatted text which is just a description of the results I have. So, I was reading this paper and I'm wondering how does the code work when there are % inside? Doesn't that mean just text? What happens if the % is removed from the code?

[image]

I know it says not enough input arguments, so I let

eradode(a,b,ze,d,Ti,dt,s1,z1,r1) be

eradode(0.005,0.0095,0.0001,0.0001,10,1,500,0,0)

but it just does computation.

[image]

So, is this a computation only code? If I remove the % on plot(t,z) it would lead me to an error because t is unknown.

The original code is on the last few pages of this paper [When Zombies Attack](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rsmith43/zombies.pdf)

I know I'm going to get why are you copying comments...here is my answer. 
I didn't feel comfortable doing the assignment because I thought that I should come up with my own, but my professor just told me to replicate the models from this paper and write the results in my own words. Well, I'm going to cite every sentence out just in case.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab the % symbol is used to indicate the start of a comment. The comments can be anywhere in the script. They are often used to describe what is happening as well as acting as an explanation. if the % symbol is removed then when you run the code matlab will read that line and attempt to run it, based on the libraries it has access to. if the text isn't actual code it will cause an error.

If you read the the description at the beginning of the function in the paper. It says that by using the defined inputs, a vector of solutions over a predetermined amount of time will be produced. So as to your question yes it is computation code. It also describes what the inputs should be in order for the function to operate correctly.

Comment: ok, but this computation code just stopped at column 11. Is that normal?

Comment: or does it compute beyond column 11? I know I typed this correctly because there weren't any red warnings or errors and I used 

eradode(0.005,0.0095,0.0001,0.0001,10,1,500,0,0) where s1,r1, and z1 are the initial values... the rest is straight forward. We're at time T - 10 and the time step is 1

Comment: but then k = ti/dt . Since the paper had k = 0.25 that would mean that I need values ti and dt that will make it k = 0.25, but the problem is that all of my computations become 0. If Ti = 25 dt = 99. Then k = 25/99 =0.252525 repeating, but all the computations go to 0 O_O!

Comment: yes sorry i just deleted my last comment i confused myself.. Ti is the amount of time between pulses which you put as 10 and dt is the time step which put as 1.. all your doing there is deciding how far apart the measured impulses are and how often if you increase either number you obtain more results.

Comment: you need to read up how eulers ode method works, and you will understand what the results mean. try this.. https://youtu.be/RGtCw5E7gBc

Comment: I've done Euler's Method before (except the school never taught it...but I read it myself anyway)... there's a lot of calculations involved for different time steps, but the ODEs I've done is a bit different than the ones on the paper. so if Ti = 25 that's the time between pulses and dt = 99 is the time step. Oh see what I've done... if I just have T = 10 I just calculated up to that point, but if T =50, I will get more calculations. So if k = 0.25 because ti =25 and dt = 99 there's no zombie.